# Send Email with PHP/AJAX From HTML Form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to send the information the user has filled out from an HTML form to my email address. From my understanding, this cannot be done by using only client-side coding due to the nature of how emails work, and suggested to use PHP (combined with AJAX) to handle the server-side code. I followed the guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051772/jquery-php-mail-send-the-easy-way) but I am not receiving any emails at my email address. I am testing locally on my machine (using XAMPP) before I deploy my code on my client's web space (goDaddy). I want to note that I have never used PHP before.

Javascript:

```
var data = "This is my email";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php",
    data: data,
    dataType: "text"
});
```

PHP (email.php):

```
<?php
$to = "myself@hotmail.com";
$subject = "This is my email";
$message = $_REQUEST;
$send = mail($to, $subject, $message);
if(!$send){    
    die();  
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a mail delivery mechanism on your local machine which can be used by php?

Comment: BTW The message will only print the text `Array`, because `$_REQUEST` is an array.

Comment: You might also need to setup your email settings in XAMPP.  Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652566/php-mail-setup-in-xampp

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you needed a mail delivery mechanism. I will install that now. What about when I deploy my code onto my client's webhost (goDaddy)? Will I need to do anything special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAMPP doesn't have an e-mail sending thing by itself as default. You may check the links below;

[php mail setup in xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652566/php-mail-setup-in-xampp)

[How do I enable XAMPP to locally use the php's mail() function so I can test my mail() scripts locally without having to upload to my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486155/how-do-i-enable-xampp-to-locally-use-the-phps-mail-function-so-i-can-test-my)

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `$_REQUEST` with `$_REQUEST["data"]` or something like this, because `$_REQUEST` is an array.

Comment: Although you are correct I doubt it will solve the issue of OP.

Comment: @PeeHaa Why? Give Uhehesh a chance to improve his/her answer.

Comment: I think my answer won't really help him with e-mail issue but will save his time thinking about why only "Array" is sent.

Comment: @Uhehesh Ah, I did not realize that. That would have saved me quite a lot of time. Thank you :)

Comment: Also if you use `$_REQUEST["data"]` then you need `data: {data: data}` in ajax call.

Comment: @Jon Did it work? In that case, Give Uhehesh a nice green root sign.

Comment: @11684 I'm not quite sure yet. I'm still trying to set-up the Mercury. I am new to XAMPP so I'm watching a video tutorial as I didn't understand the tutorials on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Jon Okay. It's just that I thought you said "Thank you, it's working" in your previous comment and I sometimes forget to accept answers.

Comment: @11684 My apologies. I'm just new to XAMPP and PHP. By any chance do you know if I will need to set up some sort of mailing mechanism on my client's webhost (goDaddy)?

Answer (score 1):

all time the page is being refreshed. Below is my code:

HTML 5:

```
<form method="post" data-ajax="false">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="jack@example.com, jil@example.com">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Invite" class="submitBtn"> 
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('form').bind('submit',function(){
$.ajax({
type    : 'POST',
url     : 'data/invite.php',
data    : $(this).serialize(),
cache   : false,
dataType: 'text',
success : function (serverResponse) { alert('mail sent successfully.'); },
error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert('error sending mail');}
});
})
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$to         = $_POST['mail'];
$name       = 'Indusnet Technologies';
$subject    = 'Think Recycle';
$text       = 'Welcome to our site';

$message =' You received  a mail from '.$name;
$message .='Text of the message : '.$text;

if(mail($to, $subject,$message)){
    echo 'mail successful send';
}
else{
    echo 'there’s some errors to send the mail, verify your server options';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = "This is my email";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php",
    data: data,
    dataType: "text"
});
```

This Code shoud be like this

```
var data = "This is my email";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php",
    data: {"data": data},
    dataType: "text"
});
```

and get in code either through $_POST['data'] or $_REQUEST['data']

Answer (score 0):

You probably should return false to the form. Try this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : 'data/invite.php',
    data    : $(this).serialize(),
    cache   : false,
    dataType: 'text',
    success : function (serverResponse) { alert('mail sent successfully.'); },
    error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert('error sending mail');}
  });

return false;
})
```